# Bifurcation analysis, limit cycle collapses on two symmetric fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation, limit-cycles, catastrophe-theory

Coming back on the system I already mentioned in another post, this time I am working on some bifurcation analysis of a 2D System.

The system is defined by the following equations. I am assuming $\tau_a >1$ to be kept fixed.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot d_{1} &= - d_1 - e_1 + \varepsilon f(d_1) \\
\tau_a \dot{e}_{1}&=g_a f(d_1) - e_{1}\\
f(d_1) &= \frac{e^{d_1}-1}{e^{d_1}+1}
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:2D_sync}
\end{equation}

In particular, one can show that a Hopf bifurcation occurs when $\epsilon>\epsilon^*,\ \epsilon^*=2(1 + \frac{1}{\tau_a})$. I mentioning it here for the sake of completeness, although it is not the main problem I am trying to solve.

> In **orange** are plotted some trajectories of the system forward in time
>
> In **blue** are plotted some trajectories of the system backward in time
>
> In **red** are plotted the nullclines

[image: Before Limit cycle]

After Hopf bifurcation:

[image]

By increasing the parameter $\epsilon$, the size of the limit cycle increases until two fixed points emerges "from inside" the limit cycle. In the picture below you can see the intersection of the two nullclines.

[image]

By further increasing $\epsilon$ the limit cycle collapses on the fixed points that become stable.

[image: 2d fixed]

Zooming on the new stable fixed points.

[image: zoom]

It looks again as an Hopf bifurcation but I did not find anything to classify it properly.

Do you have any suggestion on some more rigorous analysis/example?

**UPDATE**

Numerically I computed the value of $\epsilon^{o}=13.12$ at which the off-origin equilibria bifurcates. It is a subcritical Hopf bifurcation. In the figure below I plot the system's evolution with $\epsilon=13.23$.

[image]

and just before the *catastrophe* ($\epsilon=13.246$) (the two blue limit cycles also merge, it seems). In the plot below, only two trajectories are plotted (forward in time in orange, backward in time in blue). The initial transient has been removed as well.

[image]

I would say that the unstable (in blue) and stable (in orange) limit cycles collides and annihilate but I think I need something more rigorous or a similar system to motivate this intuitive consideration.

Comment: The equilibria that emerge inside the limit cycle appear due to pitchfork bifurcation of $(0, 0)$ when $\epsilon = g_a+2$: seems that an unstable node at $(0, 0)$ becomes a saddle and spawns two symmetric unstable nodes. It would be good to follow these equilibria further and look what bifurcations do they undergo. You can't simultaneously "Andronov-Hopf" (as a verb) on two equilibria, by the way, so the explanation must be different.

Comment: @Evgeny As far as I see, (0,0) it doesn’t look like a saddle, is it? I think Isn’t an unstable focus that spawns two symmetric unstable equilibria?

Comment: No, unstable focus can't spawn two unstable equilibria and remain completely unstable itself (index theory forbids such bifurcation). The picture around the origin is obscured by steep nullclines, but you can check eigenvalues. Note also that there is also a global symmetry in this system: for any solution $(u(t), w(t))$ holds that $(-u(t), -w(t))$ is also a solution. This might be an important observation later.

Comment: @Evgeny Yep, you are right! I will add the eigenvalues. How could this symmetry property be used?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. A stable limit cycle can disappear not only by getting stuck into an unstable equilibrium, but also in a homoclinic loop or a heteroclinic cycle. What bugs me is that this symmetry easily allows a heteroclinic cycle between two symmetric saddles, but it seems that we don't have enough equilibria to get these saddles. Maybe next morning I'll have a better idea. Studying bifurcations for off-origin equilibria should be a key to understanding here.

Comment: By the way, can you tell what values of $g_a$ and $\tau_a$ do you use? I want to fiddle a little bit with this system myself.

Comment: I am using g=10, tau_a=2. epsilon bifurcation parameter

Comment: Regarding your new observation: the unstable limit cycles that spawn from Andronov-Hopf bifurcation for off-origin equilibria get very close to a stable limit cycle when $\epsilon = 13.24$. I see them by backwards integration starting from a point close to an off-origin equilibrium. When $\epsilon = 13.25$, there is no limit cycles at all. It still doesn't look like any typical bifurcation of a limit cycle...

Comment: @Evgeny Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Well, if you have a system $\dot{x} = P(x, y), \dot{y} = Q(x, y)$, integrating it in forward time (just regular numerical integration methods) will find you attractive regimes: stable nodes/foci, stable limit cycles, etc. However, if you apply regular integration to a system $\dot{x} = {\color{red}-}P(x, y), \dot{y} ={\color{red}-}Q(x, y)$, you will find unstable regimes. That's how I find unstable limit cycle: I pick a point close to off-origin stable equilibrium and integrate the second system long enough to see the unstable limit cycle. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Ok, I got about the backward integration. It was a good suggestion that I did not consider yet. Btw bifurcation values are different for me. I will update in 10 mins up.

Comment: Just a little advice: when you pick a point far from limit cycle and plot a trajectory starting from it, there might be a long transient that has little valuable information, but makes plot less easy to read. If you can "re-pick" point closer to limit cycle, you'll have a clearer picture. Our numerics agree that at $\epsilon = 13.24$ there is still a big stable limit cycle. However, these blue limit cycles can't collide with an orange one simultaneously: if I am not mistaken, there is no such bifurcation for a limit cycle on plane. I'll add my numerics in comment later.

Comment: @Evgeny if you look at the last plot there is only one unstable colliding with one stable because the two unstable merges first. I found one example (simpler online)and  I will put it in the references as soon as I have my laptop.

Comment: Because of transients I'm not sure how many limit cycles do I see. By the way, symmetric limit cycles can get stuck into a symmetric pair of homoclinic loops and disappear. But I still can't figure out how big limit cycle is being destroyed. The easiest way would be to collide with an (possibly outer) unstable limit cycle, but I still haven't found it, so I might be wrong.

Comment: I removed the transient and the hypothesis above still seems to hold.
I found this that maybe could be interesting. I don't know much about the quality since I am new in the field but maybe it could be useful 
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4939-6389-8_9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92857/discussion-between-evgeny-and-giangian).